# Loading component only for one instance of another component in Angular

Tags: html, angular

In my component task.component.html I have a reference to a modal in which I can set the fields necessary for saving/editing the task

```
 <app-task #taskModal></app-task>
```

On my page I have n task components, and as for now if I try to open a modal just for one task from the list, the page is practically frozen. I assume it's because it's calling this modal for every one of n tasks at the same time.
Is there any way to use a modal only for one given element from a list? I'm assuing that on ngOnit this component is initialized n times, but maybe I;m wrong 
I'm filling my task.component like this. I'm using Angular 7 in my project.

```
<div *ngFor="let task of listOfTask"  class="even">
        <div style="background-color: inherit">
            <app-task-component [task]="task>
            </app-task-component>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think the ideal solution would be to move   to some grandgrandgrand parent (main page) and then in task.component only call function from that "parent" is it possible?

Comment: Actually, the page is "frozen" because you are displaying modal dialog. That's literally what "modal" means. I'd suggest using something other than a modal dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure I get Your answer. I'm using modals in may other pages and never have this problem. Also I need to have a modal here